# List of dictionary in python as HTML Table format

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, odoo, list-processing

I have list of dictionary as the below format

```
[{'duration': 0.7, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'Arya Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.9, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Ned Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 2.88, 'project_id': 7, 'resource': u'Robb Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.22, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 0.3, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 2.15, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'Arya Stark', 'activity': u'Practise'},
{'duration': 3.35, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Sansa Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 2.17, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Rickon Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 1.03, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Benjan Stark', 'activity': u'Design'},
{'duration': 1.77, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Bran Stark', 'activity': u'Testing'},
{'duration': 1.17, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Ned Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.17, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 1.77, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'catelyn stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.3, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 0.45, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'}]
```

All I need is to create a Table in python like

```
report_table = """<table>
.........
...........
..........
</table>"""
```

So the table format is attached,

[image]
1) It is possible to Bring in the desired format

2) Can we do summation operation inside dictionary data

Comment: 1) Yes. You can easily just create an HTML page and insert columns and rows as needed. 2) Yes, you can summation operation inside a dictionary.

Comment: Answer to question 1 is: YES
Answer to question 2 is: YES (if I have correctly understood it)

Show some code, effort, precise specification if you want more useful answers

Comment: Sure I will add my contribution to it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IIUC Here is a solution using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
dict_data = [{'duration': 0.7, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'Arya Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.9, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Ned Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 2.88, 'project_id': 7, 'resource': u'Robb Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.22, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 0.3, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 2.15, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'Arya Stark', 'activity': u'Practise'},
{'duration': 3.35, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Sansa Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 2.17, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Rickon Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 1.03, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Benjan Stark', 'activity': u'Design'},
{'duration': 1.77, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Bran Stark', 'activity': u'Testing'},
{'duration': 1.17, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Ned Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.17, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 1.77, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'catelyn stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.3, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 0.45, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
dfg = df.groupby(['project_id','resource','activity']).sum()
dfg.to_html('result.html')
```

Will produce a html like this:

[image]

And another solution using `pandas` [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with a different result:

```
import numpy as np

pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['duration'],index=['project_id','resource'], columns=['activity'], aggfunc=np.sum,margins=True, fill_value=0)
pvt.to_html('result2.html')
```

[image]

**Rearrange the total project wise:**
Rearrange the columns and index to get a desired rusult.

```
import numpy as np
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['duration'],index=['resource','activity'], columns=['project_id'], aggfunc=np.sum,margins=True, fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please guide me, how to get the project wise summation, for example total duration spent in project_id 3 is sum(2.85+1.77) is 4.62.

Comment: Updated the solution, you can rearrange the index and columns for a desired result.