# Pandas Pivot Table aggfunc in HOURS:MINUTES format

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

[List of dictionary in python as HTML Table format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727097/list-of-dictionary-in-python-as-html-table-format/37727402#37727402)

In the above Link, Pivot Table is created and duration is summed, but duration should be sum in `Hour.minutes` format

Note: Duration is fetched as Float not as timestamp

It's is possible in Pandas

What I tried is at the time of fetching the data itself I converted into like this

```
str(int(redmine_hours[1])/60+int(redmine_hours[0])) + '.' + str(int(redmine_hours[1]) % 60)
```

But aggfunc identify it as float value and summed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need convert column `duration` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `unit=h` (`hours`) and then [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) (I remove `[]` in parameter `value` for remove `Multiindex` in columns):

```
import pandas as pd
dict_data = [{'duration': 0.7, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'Arya Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.9, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Ned Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 2.88, 'project_id': 7, 'resource': u'Robb Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.22, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 0.3, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 2.15, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'Arya Stark', 'activity': u'Practise'},
{'duration': 3.35, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Sansa Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 2.17, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Rickon Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 1.03, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Benjan Stark', 'activity': u'Design'},
{'duration': 1.77, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Bran Stark', 'activity': u'Testing'},
{'duration': 1.17, 'project_id': 4, 'resource': u'Ned Stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.17, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 1.77, 'project_id': 3, 'resource': u'catelyn stark', 'activity': u'Development'},
{'duration': 0.3, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'},
{'duration': 0.45, 'project_id': 9, 'resource': u'Jon Snow', 'activity': u'Support'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
```

```
df['duration1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='h')
print (df)
       activity  duration  project_id       resource  duration1
0   Development      0.70           3     Arya Stark   00:42:00
1   Development      0.90           4      Ned Stark   00:54:00
2   Development      2.88           7     Robb Stark   02:52:48
3       Support      0.22           9       Jon Snow   00:13:12
4       Support      0.30           9       Jon Snow   00:18:00
5      Practise      2.15           3     Arya Stark   02:09:00
6   Development      3.35           4    Sansa Stark   03:21:00
7   Development      2.17           9   Rickon Stark   02:10:12
8        Design      1.03           4   Benjan Stark   01:01:48
9       Testing      1.77           4     Bran Stark   01:46:12
10  Development      1.17           4      Ned Stark   01:10:12
11      Support      0.17           9       Jon Snow   00:10:12
12  Development      1.77           3  catelyn stark   01:46:12
13      Support      0.30           9       Jon Snow   00:18:00
14      Support      0.45           9       Jon Snow   00:27:00
```

```
pvt1 = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                      values='duration1',
                      index=['project_id','resource'], 
                      columns=['activity'], 
                      aggfunc=np.sum,
                      fill_value=0)
print (pvt1)
activity                   Design  Development  Practise  Support  Testing  \
project_id resource                                                          
3          Arya Stark    00:00:00     00:42:00  02:09:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
           catelyn stark 00:00:00     01:46:12  00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
4          Benjan Stark  01:01:48     00:00:00  00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
           Bran Stark    00:00:00     00:00:00  00:00:00 00:00:00 01:46:12   
           Ned Stark     00:00:00     02:04:12  00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
           Sansa Stark   00:00:00     03:21:00  00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
7          Robb Stark    00:00:00     02:52:48  00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
9          Jon Snow      00:00:00     00:00:00  00:00:00 01:26:24 00:00:00   
           Rickon Stark  00:00:00     02:10:12  00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
All                      01:01:48     12:56:24  02:09:00 01:26:24 01:46:12   

activity                      All  
project_id resource                
3          Arya Stark    02:51:00  
           catelyn stark 01:46:12  
4          Benjan Stark  01:01:48  
           Bran Stark    01:46:12  
           Ned Stark     02:04:12  
           Sansa Stark   03:21:00  
7          Robb Stark    02:52:48  
9          Jon Snow      01:26:24  
           Rickon Stark  02:10:12  
All                      19:19:48
```

Comment: How does it works? Column `duration` is in `float` - it means `timedelta` in hours?

Comment: ValueError: ['d' 'u' 'r' 'a' 't' 'i' 'o' 'n' '1'] not contained in the index, we cannot values='duration1', since it is in timedelta

Comment: Yep, I tried that also, raise ValueError('%s not contained in the index' % str(key[mask]))
ValueError: ['d' 'u' 'r' 'a' 't' 'i' 'o' 'n' '1'] not contained in the index

Comment: But duration1 is available in dataframe in timestamp format, but can able to sum it up

Comment: not, it is not timestamp, it is `timedelta` - because you convert by `pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='h')`. And for me it works in last version of pandas - `0.18.1`. What is your pandas version? `print pd.versions()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115388/discussion-between-jezrael-and-vigneshwaran-thenraj).